# Validation of multiple rows in jsp using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have 3 rows having 3 columns and i need to perform validations of all the 3 rows simultaneously. 
         Dept code     Dept Id      Dept Name
          12            2            HR
          45            4            Administration
          14            6            Stores

For this i am using a loop .

```
 for(i=0 ; i<val ; i++){
    if(trim(document.form1.elements[0].value).length > 0 
       && trim(document.form1.elements[1].value).length > 0 
       && trim(document.form1.elements[3].value).length > 0
       && trim(document.form1.elements[4].value).length > 0)
    {

              //PERFORM SOME VALIDATION

    }else{

        flag=1;
    }

}

    if(flag==1){
    text+="All Fields Are Mandatory ";
             alert(text);
}
```

But it performs validation of only 1st row.I need to perform this validation for multiple rows simultaneously.
NOTE :-        element[2] is a hidden element.
Plz. help..

Comment: can you post your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is performing validation for only one row because you are always checking for one rowID. As per your requirement change the value of rowID inside the loop. For Example

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                   {
                     if(document.getElementByID((dept_code)+rowID+i) ||                                                      document.getElementByID((dept_ID)+rowID+i) ||
        document.getElementByID(dept_Name)+rowID+i)   {
    //Perform Validation
    }
```

OR

```
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                       {
                         if(document.getElementByID((dept_code)+rowID) ||                                                      document.getElementByID((dept_ID)+rowID) ||
            document.getElementByID(dept_Name)+rowID)   {
        //Perform Validation
        }
rowID++}
```

Comment: Hi, Thnx for the solution. But how do i increment the row and how to get the row ID.Just check my updated code.

Comment: Hey i got it by using document.getElementByID("dept_code"+i). Thnx @Himani Kothari.I